# Redis timeout with almost no data in the database, using the .NET client

Tags: redis

I received this error:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing GET (5000ms),
    next: GET RetryCount, inst: 3, qu: 0, qs: 1, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 7, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0,
    serverEndpoint: redis:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: 18745af38fec,
    IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000),
    WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=32761,Min=1,Max=32767), v: 2.1.58.34321
    (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

We can see that there is only a single message in the queue (qs=1) and that there are only 7 bytes waiting to be read (in=7). Redis is used by 2 processes and holds settings for the system and store logs.

It was a re-install so no logs were written and the database has probably 2-3kb of data :)

This is the only output from Redis:

```
1:C 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.293 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.293 # Redis version=6.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.293 # Configuration loaded
1:M 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.296 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.296 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
1:M 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.296 # Server initialized
1:M 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.296 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memor
y=1' for this to take effect.
1:M 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.296 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo madvise > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepag
e/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled (set to 'madvise' or 'never').
1:M 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.305 * DB loaded from append only file: 0.000 seconds
1:M 12 Sep 2020 15:20:49.305 * Ready to accept connections
```

so it looks like nothing went wrong on that side.
The 2 processes accessing it are in docker containers, so does Redis. All on a single AWS instance with a lot of ram and disk available.

this is also a one time event, it has never happened before with the same config.

I'm not very experienced with Redis; is there anything in the error message that would look suspicious?

Comment: This helped me, I did not have targetFramework in my httpRuntime tag in my web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993854/all-redis-commands-timing-out-when-using-azure-cac.html